# Invalid postback or callback argument. Event validation is enabled using '<pages enableEventValidation=“true”/>'

Tags: vb.net

how do i fix this problem.Everytime i click the view/edit button it show error page which is Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

---

```
Imports eClaim.RegistrySettings
```

Public Class currencylisting

```
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Dim mydb As New DbInterface(EHRMSWEB_CONN)
'Dim regVal As New RegistrySettings()
Dim ds As DataSet
Dim dt As DataTable
Dim path As New FilePath
Dim APPSETTINGPath As String
Dim strFirstDayofWk As String

Protected WithEvents txtSortExpression As System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox
Protected WithEvents dg As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGrid





<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> Private Sub InitializeComponent()

End Sub

Private Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Init
    'CODEGEN: This method call is required by the Web Form Designer
    'Do not modify it using the code editor.
    InitializeComponent()
End Sub



Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    If Session("UserId") = "" Or (Session("UserType") <> 3 And Session("UserType") <> 2) Then
        Response.Redirect("redirect_admin.aspx?url=login_admin.aspx")
    End If

    APPSETTINGPath = path.LocatePath(4)
    strFirstDayofWk = path.getAppSetting(2, APPSETTINGPath)

    ds = Open_CLCURRENCY(mydb.dbConnEHrmsWeb, mydb.DAeHrmsWeb, 2)
    dt = ds.Tables("CLCURRENCY")
    dg.DataSource = dt
    dg.DataBind()
End Sub

Private Sub dg_SortCommand(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridSortCommandEventArgs) Handles dg.SortCommand
    Dim dv As DataView = dt.DefaultView

    dv.Sort = e.SortExpression
    txtSortExpression.Text = e.SortExpression
    dg.DataSource = dv
    dg.DataBind()
End Sub

Private Sub dg_PageIndexChanged(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridPageChangedEventArgs) Handles dg.PageIndexChanged
    Dim dv As DataView = dt.DefaultView
    If txtSortExpression.Text <> "" Then
        dv.Sort = txtSortExpression.Text
    End If
    dg.DataSource = dv
    dg.DataBind()
End Sub

Private Sub dg_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridItemEventArgs) Handles dg.ItemDataBound

    If e.Item.ItemIndex <> -1 Then
        Dim btnExRt As Button = e.Item.FindControl("btnExRt")
        Dim strPage As String
        If e.Item.DataItem("Ex_Rt_Type") = 0 Then
            strPage = "currencyratemonthly.aspx?"
        ElseIf e.Item.DataItem("Ex_Rt_Type") = 1 Then

            strPage = "currencyrateweekly.aspx?firstday=" & strFirstDayofWk & "&"
        ElseIf e.Item.DataItem("Ex_Rt_Type") = 2 Then
            strPage = "currencyratedaily.aspx?"
        End If
        btnExRt.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "javascript:window.open('" & strPage & "CurrCd=" & e.Item.DataItem("CurrencyCd") & "','View','toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,left=0,top=0,screenX=0,screenY=0,width=675,height=500');")
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub dg_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles dg.SelectedIndexChanged

End Sub
```

End Class

### hope that you can help me out with this and thank you in advance .